# Is it possibile set up Storm on a single raspberry pi 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi, apache-storm, raspberry-pi3

I've seen on StackOverflow that's possibile develop a cluster composed of a single node.
My challenge is maybe harder: setting an apache storm environment on a single raspberry pi 3. I know that is a very limited machine to do stream computing, but mine is a research interest. Until now, I have not found system requirements to setup storm on a machine, someone can help me?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ideally it should be possible once you have Linux OS installed for e.g. [Ubuntu Mate on Raspberry Pi 3](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-for-raspberry-pi-3/).

You may be required to make sure you have these packages installed:

- Java 7
- Python 2.

Then follow below link for a basic setup of Storm:

https://github.com/vrmorusu/Storm/wiki/Apache-Storm-on-Cloudera-VM

You may build uberjar files containing Storm topology files on your local machines to avoid installation of maven and other build tool dependencies.

It would be great if you can try this and post your success story or issues seen in this forum. It will help getting more focused answer(s) for problem(s).